# How to generate a regex for number range between 0.01 - 8.50

Tags: javascript, regex

Want to generate a regex for number range between 0.01 to 8.50

Can anyone please help me out?

Have tried this so far

```
^\d{1}(\.\d{2})?$
```

Comment: regex for this comparison is overkill `return num > 0.01 && num < 8.50` would do.

Comment: Is there a reason why you want to use a regex for this? Regexes are for text patterns, things like number ranges are very bad candidates for using a regular expression.

Comment: We need a regex because we're generating textbox dynamically so we have to validate it on fly. Is there any possible solution for this?

Comment: Is 0.011 valid?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming there should be 2 digits after the dot, you might use [alternations](https://www.regular-expressions.info/alternation.html):

```
^0\.0[1-9]|0\.[1-9][0-9]|[1-7]\.[0-9]{2}|8\.(?:[0-4][0-9]|50)$
```

- `^` Start of string
- `0\.0[1-9]` Match 0.01 till 0.09
- `|` Or
- `0\.[1-9][0-9]` Match 0.10 - 0.99
- `|` Or
- `[1-7]\.[0-9]{2}` Match 1.00 till 7.99
- `|` Or
- `8\.(?:[0-4][0-9]|50)` Match 8.00 till 8.49 or 8.50
- `$` End of string

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/kPjpO1/1)

Comment: What to do if i need 1 or 2 characters after decimal
Like it should allow 1.1 as well as 1.10.

Comment: @VK Then the pattern would be a bit larger `^(?:[1-7](?:\.[0-9]{1,2})?|8(?:\.[0-4][0-9]?|\.50?)?|0\.0[1-9]|0\.[1-9][0-9]?)$` See https://regex101.com/r/kPjpO1/2/ It would allow 0, 1 or 2 digits.

Comment: This pattern `^(?:[1-7](?:\.[0-9]{1,2})|8(?:\.[0-4][0-9]?|\.50?)|0\.0[1-9]|0\.[1-9][0-9]?)$`  would allow 1 or 2 digits https://regex101.com/r/kPjpO1/3